# What Methods Can Be Employed For Using Composition Over Inheritance?

Tags: oop, inheritance, composition

I have a web application (in ASP.NET MVC) with a Quotations controller. This controller can handle multiple Quotation types, MotorQuotation, PropertyQuotation, etc...

Currently it is using inheritance i.e. a Quotation model and it's children, to model the domain. The various children classes have differences in the data they store and not their behaviors. The difference in behavior would come with their validation methods as the validations can be different dependent on what unique fields a child class may store.

The question is how would someone model the quotation objects using composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: I know they say "prefer composition to inheritance" - this isn't the same as "don't use inheritance when appropriate". Apart from this saying, what is your impetus to convert to composition?

Comment: Each quotation object could be a unique type.  Then the quotation controller would need to have a separate container for every quotation type it can handle.  There would also be additional code to iterate over all the types.

I would think this particular problem is a hand-in-glove fit for inheritance.

Consider the maintainability.  If you add a new quotation type for inheritance, you will implement a new derived class.  If you add a new quotation type for composition, you will implement a new standalone class, plus you have to modify the controller code to support a new container type.

Comment: @Amardeep I didn't quite understand your comment. What do you mean by "container"? In the controller, I have to use the parent object as the Model, and then cast it to whichever child it's supposed to be. Isn't this a bad architecture?

Comment: @Laz:  A container is something that holds instances of a particular type.  It may be a list, a vector, or a queue, etc. that holds pointers (or references) to your base class.  Then you can store any derived type in one container.  If your quote types don't have a common base class, then they must be kept in separate containers.

Comment: @Laz:  Based on your last comment it seems you may not understand how polymorphism works.  Are you aware that a derived (child) class that implements virtual methods from the base (parent) class should not need any casting to access those methods?

Comment: @Amardeep I understand polymorphism. However in the ASP.NET MVC architecture where I have strongly typed views, I could use the parent class for the List view for instance, but then the create/edit forms would have to be child-specific from what I can see. (Note the forms will contain child-specific fields).

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe the problem, it sounds like this is a good case for using inheritance.  The rule of thumb is to use inheritance if A is-a B and to use composition if A is-implemented-in-terms-of B.

The recommendation to prefer composition to inheritance does not mean "never ever use inheritance". It means use inheritance appropriately.  For example, if you write a `Stack` class in C++ using an `std::vector`, you don't want to derive `Stack` from `vector`.  A `Stack` is not a `vector`, it is implemented-in-terms-of a `vector`, which implies composition.  You also want to avoid creating deep class hierarchies, because that results in tight coupling.

In your case, however, inheritance seems like an obvious choice.

Comment: Exactly.  The "prefer composition over inheritance" rule applies specifically to the question of code reuse, not to all aspects of OO design.